# How do I obtain a cursor for a routed database?

Tags: django

django.db.connection.cursor() turns out to return a connection to default database, not a routed one.

How do I create a cursor to a database selected for my Django application by project configuration?

Answer (score 3):

`django.db` provides a dictionary of all connections, according to the keys you use in your dictionary within the settings module:

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['my_db_alias'].cursor()
```

This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/multi-db/#using-raw-cursors-with-multiple-databases).

Comment: How do you obtain 'my_db_alias' string (defined at project configuration through some complex routing procedure) at the application level?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've examined django.db.models.Model class and found out that routed connection if obtained through router each time:

```
from django.db import connections, router

using = using or router.db_for_write(self.__class__, instance=self)
connection = connections[using]
```

Unfortunately, router takes Model subclass as first argument of its db_for_write() method.